# Sending ethers in bulk to an array of addresses - advise on gas price and execution

Tags: solidity, gas-price, out-of-gas, solidity-0.8.x

Would bulk transfers work without failure/revert even if the below for loop is for 50,000 to 100,000+ accounts in bidders array?

```
mapping(address => uint) public bidderAmount;
address[] public bidders;

function bulkTransfer() external onlyAdmin {
   for(uint i = 0;i <= bidders.length - 1;i++){
       payable(bidders[i]).transfer(bidderAmount[bidders[i]]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gas cost for an ether transfer starts at 9000. See [here](https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md#aa-call-operations) for other details about the CALL opcode.

Mainnet currently has 30M as block gas limit, so at most you will be able to make 30M/9000 = 3333 transfers.

Comment: So the above code will revert if there are more than 3333 addresses in the array? If yes, May I know what is the best way to transfer to a huge number of accounts?

Note: I am usnig xDai/Gnosis chain, not ethereum. would that make any difference?

Comment: @toddash Yes, it will revert with an out of gas error. My approximation is based in opcode costs for the real number you will have to run tests, the number will be lower due to solc overhead. I checked and xdai also has gas 30M as block gas limit.